# How to permanently change html elements with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a table and each cell of this table has two mode. Two mode is a -button in cell- or 'Checked' value.

and when I clicked on button change cell value permanently to 'Checked Value'.

Comment: Can you provide some of your code relevant to this problem or situation so that someone could answer it

Comment: What do you mean by "permenently"? Do you want to update the HTML file on the server? That will require AJAX. It's better to store the data in a database and generate the table dynamically rather than updating static files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check if below code can help you.

```
<cell>
  <button onclick="checked(this);">click</button>
</cell>

<script>
  function checked(ele){
    ele.parentElement.innerHTML = "Checked"
  }
</script>
```

please consider above code as reference code. Inline event should be avoided. Also you can add some tag instead of cell (cell tag is used for understanding purpose).

Comment: There is no such element as `cell` in HTML. Additionally, inline event handling should not be used.

Comment: I want to change permanently cell of table value. I can do it by php. but I can't code with php.

Comment: my purpose from cell was - cells of a table -

Comment: and whats meaning of the tag instead of cell?

Comment: which is the parent element of button? or else can you print table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Permanent changes mean persisting the data so that a new or returning visitor can see those changes. Persisting the data can be done in a variety of ways, it can be done per user (cookies or `localStorage`) or for every user (server-side data repository).

It all depends on what architecture you are using (or willing to use) and what your needs for persistence are.

Answer (score 0):

if the value should be kept always, then in any case, the server side is needed, mainly with the database.  If stored in the client’s browser, then in cookies or localStorage.  Loop through the stored values ​​and display the table rows with the desired content.